# Unable to do forloop in R

Tags: r, pdf, data-extraction

Hi I have a number of PDF files saved in one folder. Every PDF files has number of currency value starting with $ , i want to extract the first currency value in each file , i am able to do it for single file but not when looping through number of files where i will get the the output from each file 
Like $xxx,xxx,xxx
     $xxx,xxx,xxx
     $xxx,xxx,xxx
Code when i am using for single file

''''

```
text_data <- pdf_text('Sample2.pdf')
text_collapsed_data <- paste0(text_data, collapse = '\n')
k=str_extract_all(text_collapsed_data, "\\$\\d+(?:,\\d+)(?:,\\d+)")[[1]]
k[1]
```

''''
Code when i am using to loop for multiple flies

''''

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  print(i)
  pdf_text(paste(str_extract_all("~filepath/desktop",files[i], "\\$\\d+(?:,\\d+)(?:,\\d+)")[[1]]))

}
```

''''

getting error  subscript out of bounds Let me where can i go wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
myextr <- function(pdffile) {
  text_data <- pdf_text(pdffile)
  text_collapsed_data <- paste0(text_data, collapse = '\n')
  k=str_extract_all(text_collapsed_data, "\\$\\d+(?:,\\d+)(?:,\\d+)")[[1]]
  k[1] 
}
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
sapply(files, myextr)
```